# Ping using 127.0.0.1

Tags: cisco, ping, loopback

My question is about this case : I have a PC with 2 NIC (Network interface card ) , when I do ( ping 127.0.0.1) ** which nic will be the ping tested on ? **

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localhost loopback is an entirely virtual interface. There is no hardware.